# How to make Drag and Drop Objects move in real time, with border etc in VS 2012

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, drag-and-drop

I've created a simple drag and drop experiment which in principal works fine, moving Label 1 over Label 2 and changing the text

[image]

However, you dont see the actual label move, you get an arrow with a plus sign when the mouse arrives over Label 2. Is there anyway to physically pick up the object and see it actually moving.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Label2_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles Label2.DragDrop
        Label2.Text = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString
    End Sub
    Private Sub Label2_DragEnter(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles Label2.DragEnter
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
    End Sub
    Private Sub Label1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Label1.MouseDown
        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
            Label1.DoDragDrop(Label1.Text, DragDropEffects.Copy Or DragDropEffects.Move)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26625217/how-to-draw-control-while-is-moved-in-a-drag-and-drop-event

Comment: The method depends on what you want to achieve: 1) Drag the Control itself and drop it on another 2) Move a *ghostly* representation of the source Control 3) Any of the above,  but the source Control disappears when dropped 4) Any combination of the above, with the effect that the source Control's text is merged with or instead replaces the destination Control's text.